# What is the (1) in front of the browser window title?

Tags: support

[image]

Is someone else getting this? Can someone tell me what this is? After refreshing the page, it disappears.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not a bug, it's a feature.

It means there's 1 new question for the [wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress) tag.